# I have around 17 tables in my HTML document and want them to appear separately when I click on them through a separate button

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-table

I have 17 tables in my HTML document. I want them all under a separate button. So the table for the year 2000 under a button that says: Table for year 2000 below! I can do the first one. But when I try to apply the JavaScript code for the button on other tables I keep getting the first table.

**This is my JavaScript code:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
} 
</script>
```

**This is my HTML code for the tables, I'm just showing the first 2 tables because it's 17 times copy paste:**

```
<!--Table for the year 2000 below-->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Table for the year 2000 below!</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none;">
+<table>...
</table>
<br><br><br>
</div>

<!--Table for the year 2001 below-->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Table for the year 2001 below!</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none;">
+<table>...
</table>
<br><br><br>
</div>
```

Alright so hear me out, I now with a quick Google search that `getElementById` can only hold one parameter. I got that. I tried to copy my JS code and change the ID in the function and the HTML code, but everytime I try that I can only show the latest table I applied that method to, doesn't matter which button I press.

I have also seen people on this forum use `querySelectorAll` but that didn't work out for me.

Could someone help me out with this? I expect my method to work, use the same function that works on the first table but keep changing the ID. But clearly it didn't.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried, that way we can tell you where it's going wrong.

Comment: Show us the relevant code. We can't help fix something we can't see. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please show a small snippet of code which you are trying with and having trouble with so that others can look at and guide you with.

Comment: Yeah sorry everyone, I  posted before I was finished with the question. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few inputs:

1. `Id` should be unique to an element
2. The event handler should be given some inputs to identity which *element* (`table` in this case) it has to work with.

To cover all these, a sample snippet is included to help you further.

Detailed breakdown:

1. We are attaching a [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event handler to all the `button` elements
2. We try to identify all button elements using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
3. How do we identity which `table` to show on a *click* event? We can put that additional details in `data-*` attributes. Based on that we are selecting that specific table using [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Detailed comments included in the code-base.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // Get all the `button` elements
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  // To store the current `table` 
  var currentTable = null;

  // Loop over each button element and attach an handler to `click` event
  buttons.forEach((element, index, array) => {

    element.addEventListener("click", function() {

      // Get the associated table using the `data-table` attribute of this button
      var tableId = element.getAttribute("data-table");

      // Good to go? 
      if (tableId) {

        //  Hide the current `table` if we have any displayed
        if (currentTable !== null) {
          currentTable.style.display = "none";
        }

        // Store the current table and `display` it
        currentTable = document.getElementById(tableId);
        currentTable.style.display = "table";
      }

    });

  });
}
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}

#table1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#table2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnForTable1" data-table="table1">Show Table 1</button>
<button id="btnForTable2" data-table="table2">Show Table 2</button>
<!-- Table 1 -->
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Table 2 -->
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header content 1</th>
      <th>Header content 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Body content 1</td>
      <td>Body content 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer content 1</td>
      <td>Footer content 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: worked out my man! Thanks a lot!